# Plot Arabic text from right-to-left in R

Tags: r, utf-8, arabic

I'm having trouble plotting Arabic script properly in R from right-to-left using the wordcloud package.  It renders fine on the command line and the problem seems to be with the built-in "text" command when plotting.  Note the location of the question mark in the text below versus plotting it.

```
> q="مرحبا، ما هو اسمك؟"
> Encoding(q)
[1] "UTF-8"
> plot(1:10,1:10)
> text(8,4,labels=q)
```

Comment: There have been prior questions to R-help about Hebrew and Farsi which display right to left. The `Unicode` package  might help: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+arabic+right-to-left+plot#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20arabic%20right-to-left%20plot+page:1+mid:7zevlr6hkweczuxu+state:results

Comment: hmm, can't reproduce the problem on Linux, using R 3.1.3. If I use RStudio, text is correct (right to left) in both terminal and on plot. If I invoke R from shell, the text is reversed in the terminal but still looks correct when plotted. Can we get `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: `> sessionInfo()`
`R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1`

Comment: I upgraded to R version 3.1.3 and RStudio Version 0.98.1103 and still get the same result in both the R shell and in RStudio

Comment: Yep, I tried my full "wordcloud" script on a Linux machine and everything works fine.  I guess this is why we need Reproducible research environments with Docker :) http://www.carlboettiger.info/2014/08/25/reproducible-research-environments-with-Docker.html